# javascript validation for wildcard characters and whites spaces for a text box

Tags: javascript

I have the code below:

```
 if(locationIdValue == "[!@#$%^&*()+=\\-\\[\\]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?]{1}" || locationIdValue == ' '){
      this.displayFailureMessage("Valid Location # is required.", 10000);
      canSearch = false;  
 }
```

But this validation check does not work when i hit space or enter a wild card character in my text box. Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: There's a few issues with your code, for example your "regex" isn't a regex but a string literal (to name just one). You need to show the rest (preferably in a snippet).

Comment: To expand on this, it may be worth looking into how to correctly handle regex in JS:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to do some RegEx validation however you aren't actually executing the RegEx test. Here is your code snippet corrected to actually execute the RegEx:

```js
if((/[!@#$%^&*()+=\\-\\[\\]\\\';,.\/{}|\":<>?]{1}/).test(locationIdValue) || locationIdValue == ' '){
      this.displayFailureMessage("Valid Location # is required.", 10000);
      canSearch = false;  
 }
```